# How to toggle multiple classes for child element on parent click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, slidetoggle

I am trying to toggle classes using jQuery and I'm struggling to do so. I have my HTML structure & jQuery as below

```
<div class="mainFacet bmargin5">
   <div class="head line">
      <div class="facet-title" title="Click to collapse">
         <h2 class="unit-line">Processor</h2>
         <span class="icon minus"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <ul style="display:inline-block">
        <li>i3</li>
        <li>i5</li>
        <li>i7</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.facet-title').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().children("ul").slideToggle();
            $(this).attr("title", ($(this).attr("title") == "Click to Collapse") ? "Click to Expand" : "Click to Collapse");
            $(this).toggle(function () {
                $(this).children("span").removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");
            }, function () {
                $(this).children("span").removeClass("plus").addClass("minus"); 
            });
        });
```

So its simple. I want three thing to happen on facet-title click.

- The 'ul' should toggle from "display:inline-block" to "display:none"
- The 'title' should toggle from "Click to Collapse" to "Click to Expand"
- The class's for the span should toggle  from "icon minus" to
  "icon plus".
  Now, the first two event's happen fine. Its only the 3rd event which does not. what am i doing wrong?

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2etv46v1/) to show my progress with the first 2 tasks...

Comment: First off, this is not valid: `<ul class="display:inline-block">` it should be `style="display: inline-block"` or a class name.

Comment: Oh yes. that was a mistake in typing the SO question. the HTML is fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(this).closest('.mainFacet').find('span').toggleClass("minus plus");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vteuaoe7/)**

Answer (score 1):

you are losing your reference to `this` in closures. Do the following:

```
var that = $(this);
$(this).toggle(function () {
    $(that).children("span").removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");
}, function () {
    $(that).children("span").removeClass("plus").addClass("minus"); 
});
```

**EDIT**: To explain for future readers: `this`, unlike variables, changes the object it references within a closure. So, in order to preserve the reference to the calling object (`.facet-title` in the case above), you need to assign it to a variable. This variable then can be used inside the closure.

Comment: Also, Milint's answer is probably simpler, easier to read, and more elegant ;-) However, you may find yourself in the situation that you'll need a reference to your original object within a closure function - then my answer should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
$('.facet-title').click(function () {

    var self = $(this); // create a variable to reference .facet-title

    $('span', self).toggleClass('minus plus'); // toggle plus/minus classes

    $(this).parent().siblings("ul").slideToggle(function() {

        var title;

        // Use self instead of $(this) which would refer to the ul
        self.attr('title') == 'Click to collapse' ? title = 'Click to expand' : title = 'Click to collapse';
        self.attr('title', title);
    });
});
```